301 редирект на PHP не работает коректно
на сайте сделаю редирект с помощью PHP, но коректно не работает.
В данный момент ссылка страницы работает с ИП
https://site.ru/am/post/125
Решил изменить ссылку и добавить в конец сскыли заголовок поста: https://site.ru/am/post/125-sales-manager
Когда пытаюсь зделать редирект, страница не открывается, токое впечатление что интернет отсутствует, а когда редирект делаю на тот же пост только на английскую и русскую версию, редирект работает(сайт на 3-х языках). Например так:
https://site.ru/ru/post/125-sales-manager
https://site.ru/en/post/125-sales-manager
Вот код которую з использовал:
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header('Location: https://site.ru/am/post/125-sales-manager');
die;

В чем может быть проблема?

Экспериментировать с 301 редиректом плохая идея. Очищайте кеш браузера, меняйте редирект на 302 и пока всё не будет работать на 200% не используйте 301.

Я бы предположил что вечный редирект например. ы инструменты разработчика открывали, когда тестировали? Все проблемы с запросами браузера надо смотреть там. Мы не видим что ваш сайт запрашивает

Как я и писал выше, на картинке английским по белому написано, что происходит вечный редирект

Попробуйте.
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: /125-sales-manager/");
exit();
?>

Сбросить кеши браузеров. И ваша страница 125-sales-manager должна существовать иначе в 404 должна улететь. А вообще, это не так делаеться...

Старайтесь не оставлять ответы вида "попробуйте", "может быть", и "всё не так". Пишите ответ только если вопрос имеет смысл и у вас есть конкретный ответ на него

На вопрос, невозможно дать обективный ответ не зная его настроек сервера. Для моих проектов данный ответ работает.

Так код в этом "ответе" ничем не отличается от кода в вопросе. Кроме заведомо неверной ссылки. Вопрос не про ваши проекты
